# Distance between parallel lines inside of a rectangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I have 2 parallel lines which are touching a rectangle.
I know the coordinates `(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3), (x4,y4)`

How can I find from that the orthogonal distance between the lines?

[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvJ5W.png)

Comment: Firstly, actually you need to know only three points coordinates. Secondly, think about equations of these lines. Thirdly, think how the orthogonal vector coordinates are connected with line equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s make this question a bit harder by finding the d in the following picture.

[image]

It is sufficient if we can find h and k, the co-ordinates of T.

T lies on the circle $\omega$ (with PS as diameter), whose equation is $$\omega : (x – x_1)(x – x_4) + (y – y_1)(y – y_4) = 0$$

∴ $(h – x_1)(h – x_4) + (k – y_1)(k – y_4) = 0$ …. (1)

T is also on L and hence $k – y_3 = \dfrac {y_4 – y_3 }{x_4 – x_3}(h – x_3)$ … (2)

Solving (1) & (2) will give us h and k.

Method #2

1. Use R and S to get the equation of L.
2. Use P, via the the perpendicular distance formula, to get d.

Comment: This is great ...

Comment: How did your draw this picture - which software?

Comment: @lio I am using Geogebra.

Comment: Wonderful software ... thank you for the info.